# Is my PLINQ code threadsafe?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, plinq, parallel.foreach

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Now;
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        List<string> markets = new List<string>() { "amex", "nasdaq", "nyse", "global" };

        Parallel.ForEach(markets, market =>
        {
            Downloads.startInitialMarketSymbolsDownload(market);
        }
        );

        Console.WriteLine("All downloads finished!");
    }

public static void startInitialMarketSymbolsDownload(string market)
{
    try
    {
        object valueTypeLock = new object();
        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "GOOG", "YHOO", "AAP" }

        var historicalGroups = symbolList.AsParallel().Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 100)
                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.x).ToArray());

        historicalGroups.AsParallel().ForAll(g => {
            lock (valueTypeLock) {
                getHistoricalStockData(g, market);
            }

        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}

public static void getHistoricalStockData(string[] symbols, string market)
{
    // download data for list of symbols and then upload to db tables
    Uri uri;
    string url, line;
    decimal open = 0, high = 0, low = 0, close = 0, adjClose = 0;
    DateTime date;
    Int64 volume = 0;
    string[] lineArray;
    List<string> symbolError = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> badNameError = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;

    Parallel.ForEach(symbols, symbol =>
            {
                    url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + symbol + "&a=00&b=1&c=1900&d=" + (DateTime.Now.Month - 1) + "&e=" + DateTime.Now.Day + "&f=" + DateTime.Now.Year + "&g=d&ignore=.csv";
                    uri = new Uri(url);

                    using (ooplesfinanceEntities entity = new ooplesfinanceEntities())
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(uri))
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        entity.Database.Connection.Open();

                        while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
                        {
                            line = reader.ReadLine();
                            lineArray = line.Split(',');

                            // if it isn't the very first line
                            if (lineArray[0] != "Date")
                            {

                                switch (market)
                                {
                                    case "amex":
                                        DailyAmexData amexData = new DailyAmexData();
                                        var amexQuery = from r in entity.DailyAmexDatas.AsParallel().AsEnumerable()
                                                        where r.Date == date
                                                        select new StockData { Close = r.AdjustedClose };

                                        List<StockData> amexResult = amexQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                                        if (amexResult.AsParallel().Count() > 0) // **never hits this breakpoint line**
                                        {
                                            // add the row to the table if it isn't there
                                            // now checks for stock splits and updates if necessary
                                            if (amexResult.AsParallel().FirstOrDefault().Close != adjClose)
                                            {
                                                // this means there is a stock split so it needs to have the other adjusted close prices updated
                                                amexResult.AsParallel().FirstOrDefault().Close = adjClose;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            // set the data then add it
                                            amexData.Symbol = symbol;
                                            entity.DailyAmexDatas.Add(amexData);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // now save everything
                        entity.SaveChanges();
                        Console.WriteLine(symbol + " added to the " + market + " database!");
                    }
            }
    );
}
```

Everything starts fine and I get no exceptions but I'm getting no results and the code gets stuck one the line that I marked and the memory keeps shooting up. I figured the problem was with the above code because maybe I was doing something wrong. I just don't know where to start as this is my first time dealing with plinq/parallel processing and the tutorials don't show anything this complex.

Comment: Don't lock `markets`, `Parallel.Foreach` has already given you the `market` value in a thread safe way. You just forced all processing threads to wait on the same array as everyone else, thus blocking everything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just to let you know my code wasn't working before that change. I only tried that after reading about some questions on here where people said that their code didn't work because it wasn't thread safe so I was experimenting

Comment: If you have a question about code that is not working, then you should post _that_ code, along with a detailed, specific description of in what way it doesn't work (actual behavior, any error messages, etc.), along with a clear description of how you want it to work. If you have code that does work, but you want someone to look it over, then you should post your question to codereview.stackexchange.com. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PeterDuniho I will post the full code then. I was just worried that it was too complex to post all together. I'm downloading alot of data from the internet and saving it to a database

Comment: It's thread safe. Each iteration works in its own task, receiving its own data. In any case you *don't* use `markets` anywhere inside the loop so there's no reason to lock it. The code has many problems, eg trying to download stuff with a PLINQ statement, having PLINQ inside a Parallel.Foreach,etc. Both Parallel.Foreach *and* PLINQ will try to use all cores so you simply waste tasks this way.

Comment: "I will post the full code then" -- Please don't post the "full code". That's pretty much always a mistake. See the link regarding MCVE I mentioned before. The code example should be not only complete, but also _minimal_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I read the link and I posted the minimum amount of code to show what it does so that should be alright I hope

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used plinq and the parallel.foreach because I have been reading tutorials online on how to optimize my code since my computer has an 8 core processor. Should I delete certain plinq references then do you think? What do you suggest?

Comment: I can't see what line you marked.

Comment: @user3610374: I think you have misunderstood the references. "Minimal" doesn't mean the least amount of code you can conveniently extract from your whole program. It means the smallest possible code example that reproduces the _behavior_. You need to spend enough time to _construct_ a code example that will reliably reproduce the same problem on anyone else's computer, in the least number of lines of code possible. That is, of course, if you really want someone to take the time to help you.

Comment: @user3610374: not to mention that the code example you've posted still isn't _complete_. There is extensive use of the `Helpers` class throughout, which you did not include. Not that a true MCVE likely would include that class, but this particular code example is incomplete without it. Again, someone else needs to be able to actually _run_ the code unmodified.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ok I believe I edited the code correctly to take out all unnecessary classes that I have built in the backend. This code should be able to run for anybody now. Thank you for the helpful advice

Comment: @Jodrell That was my mistake when I was editing. I made it bold and readded it so it should be very visible now

Comment: @user3610374: you can verify for yourself whether you have created a suitable code example by creating an empty project in Visual Studio, copying the code example you've posted into that empty project, and compiling it. If it can compile and run with no errors, you have succeeded. If you can't, you have not. Please don't post code that you yourself have not verified in that way, to ensure it can compile, run, and reproduce the problem you're asking about.